# Can an SVN checkout contain another SVN branch?

Tags: svn

Ok, I know it's a bit of a ghetto setup, but as to the why's, it's just another one of "those things".

Here's the setup.

In subversion, I've got two projects within one repo:

```
svn/path/projectA
svn/path/projectB
```

In the physical directory, I need to have projectA contain a checkout of projectB:

> /projectA/projectB

I could just move projectB into projectA, but that presents with a bit of a project on our end.

The other option I thought of is creating and ignoring the projectB folder within projectA, but I'm not sure if there might be some "gotcha" taking this path.

The first option is not a "can't do".  I just want to take the option with the least pains.  Are there any potential issues that might occur in the second setup?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Be aware that "ghetto", as opposed to denoting something of poor quality, is a place many people must call home.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghetto

Comment: This is a fact I'm aware of first hand having called it home myself before ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out "svn externals"

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  This is a brand new SVN concept for me.  And it appears to be exactly what I need

Comment: Beware though that it can be problematic at times to use (but so is maintaining separate repos i suppose).

Comment: Yeah.  I'm discovering that the whole idea is just plain wrong when trying to maintain a trunk/branches/tags setup.  Great thing to know about though!